# Upload a post with description and title using facebook c# sdk

Tags: windows-phone, facebook-c#-sdk

I used the following code. Picture is posted successfully with a name but its not able to post message/description with it. Please tell me where i am wrong. Also its not giving any exception.

```
 private void SharePhoto(string _accessToken, string p)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
        fb.PostCompleted += (o, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Error != null)
                {
                    if (args.Error.Message.StartsWith("(OAuthException - #190)"))
                    {
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            { MessageBox.Show("Message Expired"); });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            { MessageBox.Show(args.Error.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK); });
                    }
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        { MessageBox.Show("Image Posted"); });
                }
            };

        var fbupload = new FacebookMediaObject 
        {
            FileName = "facebook.jpg",
            ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        };
        StreamResourceInfo sri =Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("facebook.jpg",UriKind.Relative));
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
        var loadedImage = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            loadedImage.SaveJpeg(ms, loadedImage.PixelWidth, loadedImage.PixelHeight, 0, 95);
            ms.Seek(0, 0);
            byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            ms.Close();
            fbupload.SetValue(data);
        }

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();           
        parameters["message"] = txtMessage.Text;
        parameters["description"] = "first ever one";

        parameters["name"] = "My FB Pic";
        parameters["picture"]=fbupload;
        parameters["link"] = new Uri(@"http://www.anyxyz.com", UriKind.Absolute);
        fb.PostAsync(@"me/photos", parameters);

    }
```

I used extended permissions as:

```
 private const string extendedPermissions = "user_about_me,read_stream,publish_stream";
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no `description` and `link` parameters for _photo_ uploads, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos I think you might actually want to post a _link_ instead, so see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: ok, can we post message/caption with a photo?

Comment: Can _we_ please read the …ing documentation, if you were already linked to the exact place?

Comment: I want to post an image and a question related to it. so is there any way i can post both image and question with it.

Comment: If you just want your question to be shown with the photo, then why don’t you just put your question into the `message` parameter? (And please be aware that posting a message that the user has not typed in somewhere themselves violates FB’s Platform Policies [unless you will just be using that for yourself only].)

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer but i have already tried with message parameter. Its just posting image but not able to post message.